# React - override redux prop by parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Saying i have a `Container` connected to redux via:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ MyReducer }) => ({
    myProp: MyReducer.myProp
});
```

Is it possible to force the value of myProp by the parent (override redux)?

I've tried:

```
<Container myProp={"notReduxValue"}/>
```

But `mapStateToProps` overrides the provided value.

NOTE: I can't change the container, my question is if it can be done via the parent only.

(Of course this implies a bad state design but unfortunately it has come to that)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` accepts [two arguments](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). So I guess you could override it by:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ MyReducer }, { myProp }) => ({
  myProp: myProp || MyReducer.myProp,
})
```

In case you want to override `myProp` in an upper level, you can use `connect`'s `mergeProps` to do so (as @OrB also described).

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ MyReducer }, { myProp }) => ({
  myProp: MyReducer.myProp,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({ ... })

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => ({
  ... // make your changes here
})

const ConnectedContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps
)(Container)
```

Comment: I would actually use [`mergeProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for that.

Comment: @OrB sure! I didn't mention that because his example doesn't have `mapDispatchToProps` implementation and in order to prevent a rather confusing answer I've decided to omit that. But of course, `mergeProps` is also valid :)

Comment: @mersocarlin thanks for answering, so i'll take it there's no way to do it without touching the container code?

Comment: @Daniel yes. If your rule doesn't permit you to change the container's code, that's what I would do.

Comment: Who the heck decided Redux props should win over parent/user-supplied props? Gosh darn.